# Close dropdown in header when i open dropdown in footer (dropdowns have same class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a single type of dropdown in the whole website that behaves in a certain way:

1. it must open on click
2. it must stay open when i click inside the block that shows
3. it must close if i click outside of the opened block
4. it must close if i click again on the title * which opened the dropdown
5. **if i click on a new dropdown, any existing opened dropdown must close**

As you can see in my demo, i have all the features working except last one which works ok only partial. 
If you click on dropdown 1 and than on dropdown 2, all is perfect. New one that opens will close the old one which was already opened.

Now, open again dropdown 1 (from header) and after this, click to open dropdown 3 or 4 (which are in footer area) and you will see that the dropdown from header will remain opened.

Any solution to fix this? So same type of dropdown, when opened, must close previous opened drodown regardless of it's position in the webpage. Thanks

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});
$(document).click(function(event) {
  $(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});

$(".dropdown-title").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".dropdown-values").fadeToggle(500);
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-title').toggleClass("activated");
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  height: 200px;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown {
  background: #313654 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-title {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: medium none;
}
.dropdown-values {
  background: #0089d7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 1 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 1 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 2 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 2 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 3</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 3 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 3 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 4</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 4 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 4 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you can do is just call the effect of hiding the dropdowns on all of the .dropdown items (optionally use `.not(this)`), then call the effect of showing the current dropdown (if you didn't specify `.not(this)`). This way you get to avoid all that `.parents()`, `.find()`, and `.siblings()` bologna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly modified your code, you need just play with the selectors.

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});
$(document).click(function(event) {
  $(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});

$(".dropdown-title").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".dropdown-values").fadeToggle(500);
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-title').toggleClass("activated");
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  height: 200px;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown {
  background: #313654 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-title {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: medium none;
}
.dropdown-values {
  background: #0089d7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 1 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 1 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 2 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 2 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 3</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 3 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 3 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">dropdown 4</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">dropdown 4 content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">dropdown 4 content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your solution because you provided a demo and most important, it works perfect. Just test it in my website and behaves perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the problem line is this:

```
    $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
```

You're only removing the activated class in the parent.

Just look for `$('.dropdown')` directly.